# Where are examples of `?`, `??`, `<++=`, `<+=` in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm reading the [sbt document](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/api/#sbt.SettingKey), found there are some special methods I've never used:

```
?
??
<++=
<+=
```

Where can I find any examples of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SBT 0.13 did a great job eliminating the need for these operators and simplify build definition to `:=`, `+=` and `++=` with the help of macros and the special "extractor" `.value`. So no need for these operators anymore. The only thing I'm still using is `~=` were you can apply some function to the value of some setting, but it also can be expressed with `:=` and `.value`

Answer (score 3):

In your question, I think you've mixed two sets of operations - one with `<+=` and `<++=` that was or are about to be "deprecated" in favour of `:=`, `+=` and `++=`, and another with `?` and `??` that's *unfortunately* not very often used since all can be expressed with `:=`, `+=` and `++=` (and people often find using 3 enough for their use cases).

Read the official documentation of sbt in [More operations](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html#More+operations) about `?` and `??`.

As for examples:

- `?`

  ```
  lazy val unintiedKey = settingKey[String]("Unitialized key")

  lazy val someKey = settingKey[String]("Key to check the value of another")

  someKey := unintiedKey.?.value getOrElse "new value"
  ```

  What do you think is going to be printed out with `show someKey` given the above `build.sbt`?

  ```
  > show someKey
  [info] new value
  ```

  When you add the following to the `build.sbt` to have the `uninitedKey` setting initialized:

  ```
  unintiedKey := "Another value"
  ```

  `someKey` changes, too:

  ```
  > show unintiedKey
  [info] Another value
  > show someKey
  [info] Another value
  ```
- `??`

  Let's define a build with the following `build.sbt`:

  ```
  lazy val unintiedKey = settingKey[String]("Unitialized key")

  lazy val someKey = settingKey[String]("Key to check the value of another")

  someKey := (unintiedKey ?? "uninitedKey had no value").value
  ```

  Guess what the value of `someKey` is going to be?

  ```
  > show someKey
  [info] uninitedKey had no value
  ```

The key to understand the operations (that make up the [sbt.SettingKey](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/api/#sbt.SettingKey) API) is to understand what a setting is in sbt - it's a pair of a key and an initialization that gets transformed into a useable setting when a scope gets applied to it.